# How does Kotlin recognize a lambda receiver in a "use" function

Tags: kotlin

When I look at sample code for the "use" function in Kotlin, I usually see something like this:

```
private fun readFirstLine(): String {
    BufferedReader(FileReader("test.file")).use { return it.readLine() }
}
```

However, in the following example, I don't understand where "input" comes from, since input -> appears to be a lambda. From my understanding, everything inside of use { } must be an expression:

```
val streamIn = resources.openRawResource(rawResId)
val streamOut = FileOutputStream(destFilename)

streamIn.use { input ->
    streamOut.use { output ->
        input.copyTo(output)
    }
}
```

"input" clearly refers to the same object that "streamIn" refers to, but I don't understand how Kotlin knows that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> everything inside of use { } must be an expression

If you looked at the [signature](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html), you'll see that `use` takes a `(T) -> R` function, so really, any function/lambda that accepts the closable thing as a parameter can be passed to it.

With that misconception cleared up, let's see what the code in question is doing.

```
streamIn.use { input ->
    streamOut.use { output ->
        input.copyTo(output)
    }
}
```

First we see `streamIn.use {`, which means we are going to do something with `streamIn` and then close it. And from now on `streamIn` will be called `input`. Then there is `streamOut.use {`, which indicates that we are also going to use `streamOut` to do stuff, and then close it, and we are going to call it `output` from now on.

> I don't understand where "input" comes from

It's basically giving another name to the `it` as in your first code snippet. Since we have nested lambdas here, we can't use `it` to refer to the parameters of both lambdas.

> "input" clearly refers to the same object that "streamIn" refers to, but I don't understand how Kotlin knows that.

This is because in the implementation of `use`, there's probably a line like this:

```
return block(this)
```

`block` is the lambda parameter you pass to `use`, and `this` is the object on which `use` is called. Since `input` is the parameter of the lambda, it refers to `this`.

Now we have declared that we are going to use two resources, what are going to do with them? `input.copyTo(output)`! Whatever `copyTo` returns is going to be returned by `streamOut.use`, which in turn is going to be returned by `streamIn.use`. `streamOut` and `streamIn` will also be closed one after another.

So overall what have we done? We have basically used 2 resources at the same time and closed them afterwards. This is how you'd *compose* `use` to use multiple resources at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I really wasn't concerned about how the the code actually works. I understand that. I am trying to understand that how Kotlin knows where "input" comes from. Sure, it takes a lambda as a parameter, but how does it know that the "input" refers to the same object that streamIn does? Or is that some sort of built-in mechanism in Kotlin that it simply takes whatever the "use" function is bound to as the lambda receiver?

Comment: @AndroidDev I have edited the answer, but let me ask you a question back. How does the compiler know that `it` refers to the `BufferedReader` in your first snippet?

Comment: @AndroidDev The idea is that both `it`, `input` and `output` are parameter names for the lambdas. They can be whatever you want. If there is only one parameter, the name is by default `it`. You can specify what parameter name you want by writing that before `->`. As for why the parameter is the same stream on which you called `use`, that's because how `use` works. From the docs: "Executes the given block function on this resource", so `use` will call the lambda and pass in the resource as the parameter.

Comment: I was not aware that "it" and a lambda receiver are equivalent. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in the lambda, you can define a name for your object so in the following code the `input` is equivalent to `it` which is `streamIn` and output is equivalent to `streamOut`:

```
streamIn.use { input ->
    streamOut.use { output ->
        input.copyTo(output)
    }
}
```

The reason that they define `input` and `output` is you cannot use it when you use a lambda block inside another lambda block.

Answer (score 0):

`use` is an **extension function** which takes whatever calls it as a parameter.

Assume this example:

```
file.bufferedReader().use{
   println(it.readText()) // it is actually that object that calls `use`
}
```

According to the [API docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/use.html) of Kotlin, this is the schema of `use`:

```
inline fun <T : AutoCloseable?, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R
```

The `bufferedReader` in my example is a closable class.

When you write `somethingClosable.use { }`, you are in fact passing a lambda function to it, like:

```
fun <T, R> function(t: T): R {
   // use T and return an R
}

somethingClosable.use(function)
```

And inside `use` your function will be called.

[More info](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) on extension functions in Kotlin.